# How do I put an If then statement into a mysql_fetch_array() statement in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, html-table

I have one database and table that grabs OID results and inserts them into a table. This table has multiple types of values inside it that I need the final table to be able to differentiate between. I have the results sorted with a group by and I have the results filtered into a table through `mysql_fetch_array()`.

Heres what I have code wise.

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(t1)AS t1, device, test, value FROM ACRC WHERE        test='Fan Speed' GROUP BY device, test ORDER BY device ASC, test ASC LIMIT 4");

echo "<table border='3' cellpadding='3'>
    <tr>
    <th>Timestamp</th>
    <th>Unit</th>
    <th>Test</th>
    <th>Result</th>
    </tr>
    <tbody>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>". $row['t1']. "</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['device']. "</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['test']. "</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['value']." %</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
    }


$result = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(t1)AS t1, device, test, value FROM ACRC WHERE test<>'Fan Speed' GROUP BY device, test ORDER BY  test ASC, device ASC LIMIT 8");


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
    echo"<tr>";
    echo"<td>". $row['t1']. "</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['device']. "</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['test']. "</td>";
    echo"<td>". $row['value']." F</td>";
    echo"</tr>";
    }


echo"</table>";
```

This set up currently works but I want to compress it into one `mysql_fetch_array()` using an if/then/else statement in that whenever fan speed is in the test column, the value has a % added to the end of it's table square and whenever a temperature shows up in the test column, I need a F to appear in the value square. The data is currently stored as a simple integer in my database.

```
 --------------------
|Fan Speed  | 55   % |
----------------------
|Temperature| 70   F |
 --------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Just get rid of your WHERE condition such that all results appears in one query. Then, as you mention in your question title, use an `if()` condition where you echo out the results to determine if you output a `%`, `F`, or whatever next top the value.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['t1']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['device']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['test']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['value']; ?> <?php echo('$row['test'] === 'Fan Speed' ? '%' : 'F'); ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
```

Or, if you want to get fancy and keep your code clean you could even use cases statements in your SQL query to populate a new field like this:

```
SELECT
  MAX(t1)AS t1,
  device,
  test,
  value,
  (CASE test WHEN 'Fan Speed' THEN '%' ELSE 'F') AS symbol
FROM ACRC
...
```

And the code could be:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['t1']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['device']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['test']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['value'] . ' ' . $row['symbol']; ?></td>
</tr>
<?php
    }
```

Comment: I can't seem to get either example of your working right, maybe its all the <?php 's in it throwing me off since my table is entirely encapsulated by php.

Answer (score 0):

if i dont understand correctly let me know !

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
if( $row['value']==70)
{
    echo"<tr>";

    echo"<td>". $row['device']. "</td><td>F</td>";

    echo"</tr>";
    }else
{
 echo"<tr>";

    echo"<td>". $row['device']. "</td><td>" % . "</td> 

    echo"</tr>";
}
}
```

Comment: Your syntax doesn't make sense to me since the If value is grabbing from static numbers. The values will change every 5 minutes with my crontab updating the database.